# How to query rows with a minute/hour step interval in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to query memory logs off a MySql database. I am using:

`session.query(Memory).filter(Memmory.timestamp.between(from_date, to_date))`

but the results after using the time window are still too many.

Now I want to query for results withing the time window, but filtered down by asking for entries logged every X minutes/hours and skipping the ones between, but cannot find a simple way to do it.

To further elaborate, lets say the 'l's are all the results from a query in a given timewindow:

`lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll`

To dilute them, I am looking for a query that will return only the 'l's every X minutes/hours so that I am not overwhelmed:

`l......l......l.....l......l......l......l.....l.....l.....l.`

I could get everything and then write a function that does this, but that beats the purpose of avoiding choking with results in the first place.

*Sidenote:
Worse comes to worse, I can ask for a row after skipping a predifined number of rows, using mod on the row id column. But it would be great to avoid that since there is a timestamp (DateTime type of sqlalchemy).*

Edit:
There could be some value using `group by` on timestamp and then somehow selecting a row from every group, but still not sure how to do this in a useful manner with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your from_date and to_date are just dates. If you set them to python datetime objects with the date/times you want your results between, it should work.

Comment: The problem is that results remain to be too many. I need to bring them with intervals of say 5 minutes, within the given dates.